# Refactoring jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, html

Here I have 4 div tags. it works perfectly fine, but I want to know if there anyway I can refactor or concatenate selector that corresponds to each div.

```
$('.expand-one').click(function () {
$('.content-one').toggle();
});

$('.expand-two').click(function () {
$('.content-two').toggle();
});

$('.expand-three').click(function () {
$('.content-three').toggle();
});

$('.expand-four').click(function () {
$('.content-four').toggle();
});

<div class="expand-one>click to expand</div>
<div class="content-one">
<p>here is content</p>
</div>

<div class="expand-two>click to expand</div>
<div class="content-two">
<p>here is content</p>
</div>

<div class="expand-three>click to expand</div>
<div class="content-three">
<p>here is content</p>
</div>

<div class="expand-four>click to expand</div>
<div class="content-four">
<p>here is content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a common class to each "expand-*" and "content-*" div and use those. Make sure to close the quotes this time.

Comment: Since the content div elements always come right after, you can just use `$(this).next()`. And give the expand div elements a common class so you only need to bind the click event listener once.

Comment: Most likely more on topic for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), provided you fix the class attribute typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting by class, do it by data-attr, passed through as a variable:

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $('.content[data-attr=' + $(this).data('attr') + ']').toggle();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none
}

div:nth-of-type(1),
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: red
}

div:nth-of-type(3),
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: green
}

div:nth-of-type(5),
div:nth-of-type(6) {
  color: blue
}

div:nth-of-type(7),
div:nth-of-type(8) {
  color: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="expand" data-attr="one">click to expand</div>
<div class="content" data-attr="one">
  <p>here is content</p>
</div>

<div class="expand" data-attr="two">click to expand</div>
<div class="content" data-attr="two">
  <p>here is content</p>
</div>

<div class="expand" data-attr="three">click to expand</div>
<div class="content" data-attr="three">
  <p>here is content</p>
</div>

<div class="expand" data-attr="four">click to expand</div>
<div class="content" data-attr="four">
  <p>here is content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```js
$('.expand-one, .expand-two, .expand-three, .expand-four').click(function (e) {
  var contentIndex = e.target.className.substr(7, e.target.className.length);//mind that 7 is a fixed number in case it is going to be ".expand-" for every case
  $('.content-' + contentIndex ).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion to use a common class. So something like this:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="expand-one expand-header">...</div>
<div class="content-one expand-content">...</div>
<!-- and so on -->
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$('.expand-header').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.expand-content').toggle();
}
```

However, if for some reason you cannot use a common class, you could potentially use "class starts with" selector syntax, so:

```js
// Handle click for each element whose class name beings with "expand-"
$('[class^="expand-"]').click(function () {
    // Toggle the "next" element with class starts with "content-"
    $(this).next('[class^="content-"]').toggle();
}
```